# Cannot find dev_appserver.py after installing Google Cloud SDK on Mac OSX

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I installed the Google Cloud SDK using the following command:

```
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com/ | bash
```

The installation went well, I believe.

When I try to run app locally by doing `dev_appserver.py appengine-try-php`, dev_appserver.py is not found.

I expect "dev_appserver" to be either in the top directory or the bin directory of SDK, but it is not there, then where is it?

Here is of the content of those two directories.

```
Steves-MacBook-Pro:google-cloud-sdk stong$ ls -l
total 104

-rw-r--r--   1 stong  staff    982 Nov  3 11:44 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--   1 stong  staff    696 Nov  3 11:44 README
-rw-r--r--   1 stong  staff  12718 Nov  3 11:44 RELEASE_NOTES
drwxr-xr-x   8 stong  staff    272 Sep 10 06:25 bin
-rw-r--r--   1 stong  staff   1602 Nov  3 11:44 completion.bash.inc
-rw-r--r--   1 stong  staff   1651 Nov  3 11:44 completion.zsh.inc
drwxr-xr-x   4 stong  staff    136 Jan  1  1980 help
-rwxr-xr-x   1 stong  staff    880 Nov  3 11:44 install.bat
-rwxr-xr-x   1 stong  staff   3009 Nov  3 11:44 install.sh
drwxr-xr-x  21 stong  staff    714 Jan  1  1980 lib
-rw-r--r--   1 stong  staff    296 Nov  3 11:44 path.bash.inc
-rw-r--r--   1 stong  staff    278 Nov  3 11:44 path.zsh.inc
drwxr-xr-x   5 stong  staff    170 Aug 12 14:03 platform
-rw-r--r--   1 stong  staff     39 Nov  8 22:45 properties
Steves-MacBook-Pro:google-cloud-sdk stong$ ls -l bin

total 40

drwxr-xr-x  14 stong  staff   476 Aug 12 14:03 bootstrapping
-rwxr-xr-x   1 stong  staff  2607 Sep 10 06:25 bq
-rwxr-xr-x   1 stong  staff  2796 Oct 20 10:17 gcloud
-rwxr-xr-x   1 stong  staff  2611 Sep 10 06:25 gcutil
-rwxr-xr-x   1 stong  staff  2644 Oct 20 10:17 git-credential-gcloud.sh
-rwxr-xr-x   1 stong  staff  2643 Sep 10 06:25 gsutil
```

Comment: it has it's own SDK: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads

Comment: You should use "gcloud preview app run" instead.